# Printing out word by word using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, split, c-strings

I am trying to make a program that prints out a sentence word by word using a pointer. I am having hard time finding the problem.

```
    char str[100];
    char *p;

    printf("\nSentence: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    p=str;

    while(*p!='\0'){
        if(*p == ' '){
            printf("\n");
        }else{
            printf("%c", *p);
        }
        p++;
    }
```

Comment: You should look up the [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` to get a whole line.  `%s` will stop at a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using of the function `scanf` with the format `"%s"` skips leading white spaces and reads characters until a white space is encountered.

So you can not enter a sentence using this format,

Instead use the standard function `fgets`.

Moreover take into account that the user can separate words with several spaces or tabs. In this case your output will be invalid because there will be many empty lines.

It is more efficient to use the standard C functions `strspn` and `strcspn`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char str[N] = "";

    printf( "Enter a Sentence: " );

    fgets( str, N, stdin );

    str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    const char *p = str;

    const char *delim = " \t";

    while ( *p )
    {
        p += strspn( p, delim );

        const char *q = p;

        p += strcspn( p, delim );

        if ( p != q )
        {
            printf( "%*.*s\n", ( int )( p - q ), ( int )( p - q ), q );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If for example to enter the following statement

```
Have a nice day Luka Milicevic
```

then the program output will be

```
Enter a Sentence: Have a nice day Luka Milicevic
Have
a
nice
day
Luka
Milicevic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gets_s` instead of `scanf("%s")`:

```
gets_s(str, sizeof(str));
```

Then you code will work fine.

`scanf("%s")` will get only one word from standard input.

On the other hand, `gets_s` will get a whole line.

But gets_s() can work only on Visual Studio, in order to make it portable, it's better to use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` will read until first whitespace ,so only first word will be stored in `str`.

use `fgets` instead of `scanf`:(using `fgets` is a safe way)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    char* p;

    printf("\nSentence: ");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    p = str;

    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (*p == ' ') {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("%c", *p);
        }
        p++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` reads the string until the first whitespace. If you input a sentence like 'first second', only 'first' will be read. To read a full line, you should use `fgets`.

Try to avoid using `gets`, as it doesn't limit the number of characters to read, which could cause a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `scanf` like

```
scanf("%99[^\n]", str);
```

It will read any non `'\n'` (line ending) character upto max 99 so your buffer won't overflow.

Although using `fgets` is a safer bet.